# Magento/Zend XMLRPC Security Bug?

Tags: security, zend-framework, magento, xml-rpc

I've got two Magento stores and read that there is an important security problem that has been revealed.

I have downloaded the patch files, but cannot seem to understand how to patch the files properly, one store has hosting with SSH access - but the other doesn't.

How can I patch the files properly on each machine?

Source. http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/important-security-update-zend-platform-vulnerability/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can go about fixing your issue,

### For your server with SSH

Here is an example as to how to apply the patch file via SSH for a 1.4 store

```
cd /home/mystore/public_html
wget -O zendxml_fix.patch  http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.7.0.2/CE_1.4.0.0-1.4.1.1.patch
patch -p0 < zendxml_fix.patch
```

Here are the URLs for each patch,

1. [Community Edition 1.4.0.0 through 1.4.1.1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.7.0.2/CE_1.4.0.0-1.4.1.1.patch)
2. [Community Edition 1.4.2.0](http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.7.0.2/CE_1.4.2.0.patch)
3. [Community Edition 1.5.0.0 through 1.7.0.1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.7.0.2/CE_1.5.0.0-1.7.0.1.patch)

### For your server WITHOUT SSH

We have downloaded all the installations and pre-patched the files for people that don't have access to command line or the `patch` application. The contents of the files are far too big to post on here, but you can download them direct from our site

**Community Edition 1.4.0.0 through 1.4.1.1**

1. [./lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php](http://security.sonassi.com/1.4.0.0_lib_Zend_XmlRpc_Request.php.txt)
2. [./lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php](http://security.sonassi.com/1.4.0.0_lib_Zend_XmlRpc_Response.php.txt)

**Community Edition 1.4.2.0**

1. [./lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php](http://security.sonassi.com/1.4.2.0_lib_Zend_XmlRpc_Request.php.txt)
2. [./lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php](http://security.sonassi.com/1.4.2.0_lib_Zend_XmlRpc_Response.php.txt)

**Community Edition 1.5.0.0 through 1.7.0.1**

1. [./lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php](http://security.sonassi.com/1.5.0.0_lib_Zend_XmlRpc_Request.php.txt)
2. [./lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php](http://security.sonassi.com/1.5.0.0_lib_Zend_XmlRpc_Response.php.txt)

### For more information

We've posted an explanation about the issue and a solution on our own website, http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/important-magento-security-update-zend-platform-vulnerability/

Answer (score 1):

FYI, WebGuys has provided an interface for checking if your magento store is vulnerable or not: 
http://webguys.de/magento-exploit-test/

In order to apply patch file you can use either of two approaches:
1> Using SSH with following command:

```
patch -p0 < CE_1.5.0.0-1.7.0.1.patch
```

(Make sure you uploaded the patch file to the www-root of Magento installation and run the ssh command from there)

2>
Manually going through the files: `lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php` & `lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php` and adding/removing lines as mentioned in the .patch file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for your link of testing store is vulnerable or not.. Thank you @MagePsycho

Comment: I'd be a bit weary of using a service like that to test your site for vulnerabilities. I don't know the webguys, so I don't mean to imply they would do so, but it would be all too easy to keep a log of sites that are vulnerable for nefarious purposes. Magento/Varien should have really provided this service.